# Error: conflicting types for function, function declared in header file

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors

so I'm trying to compile a multifile program using makefiles and header files etc. I've got this one program that I keep on getting the same error for even though I've double checked the type a million times. Help!

### Errors:

`search.c:11: error: conflicting types for 'search'
 search.h:1: note: previous declaration of 'search' was here`

### This is my .h file

```
int search(struct intnode** root, int lookingfor, int* counter);
```

### This is my .c file

```
#include "search.h"
#include "intnode.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Usage:
  search(root, value);
*/

int search(struct intnode** root, int lookingfor, int* counter) {

  /*COMPARE TO ROOT KEY*/
  /*IF EQUAL*/
  if(int_compare(lookingfor, (*root)->key) == 0) {
    printf("%d exists in tree", lookingfor);
    counter++;
    if ((*root)->R != NULL && (*root)->key == (*root)->R) {
      search((*root)->R, lookingfor, *counter);
    }
  }

  /*IF GREATER THAN AND THERE IS A CHILD*/
  else if(int_compare(lookingfor, (*root)->key) == 1 && (*root)->R != NULL) {  
    search((*root)->R, lookingfor, *counter);
    counter++;
  }

  /*IF LESS THAN AND THERE IS A CHILD*/
  else if(int_compare(lookingfor, (*root)->key) == 2 && (*root)->L != NULL) {
    search((*root)->L, lookingfor, *counter);
    counter++;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: returning `NULL` when `int` is the return type is probably not a good idea. Keep return type `void` if nothing is to be returned.

Comment: are you sure that's _all_ you have?

Comment: Baybe you must switch `intnode.h` and `search.h` includes

Comment: Can you show code for the header files also.

Comment: `search.h` needs to do `struct intnode;` before the prototype (or preferably include intnode.h assuming there are no circular dependencies)

Comment: The signature of `search` function indicates that it returns `int`.  Whereas the function `search` returns `NULL`.  `NULL` is a macro in stddef.h  and it may be defined as `((void*)0)`; (in few other compilers/ headers - it is also defined as  `0` or `0L`). So change the function return-type to `void`.

Comment: @haris thanks, I've changed that but until i switched the #includes it didn't help!

Comment: @LPs, thanks for that tip! :-)

Comment: @LollyW No prob, i was just pointing out a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `intnode` is defined before `search()` is declared.

Comment: Thank you! All I had to do was switch the #includes to fix it, I think. Well, it's working now anyway :-)

Comment: @LollyW You should never have to switch the order of `#include` directives or something is wrong with your program design. The solution here is to put the intnode.h include inside search.h. Switching the order of `#include "search.h"` and `#include intnode.h` in the c file does not solve the problem, but if you are unlucky it temporarily fixes the problem until next time you get the same issue.

Comment: @Lundin it seemed to fix it for the moment, I also included header guards into my node header file which contributed too.

Answer (score 0):

`#include "intnode.h"` should be placed in search.h.

It is a good habit to include all needed header files needed for your .h + c code module from the header file.

Also use header guards in every h file:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

// code here

#endif // MY_HEADER_H
```

Comment: Thanks @lundin, just before you posted this I changed it, but thanks for confirming that that's another thing I needed to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error as you when compiling your code. As well as many others.

The main issue is that `struct intnode` is not defined at all.
Maybe it is defined but you have not posted its code here. But we can only give advice with what you have. Maybe it was defined in intnode.h in which case including it at the start of search.h would solve this particular issue.

I have edited that code and I get no compilations errors.
The main change was defining a `struct intnode`.
The way I have defined it is a guess. Which `struct intnode` you need is up to you, but you need one for sure.
Also have changed return type for `search` to `void*`.
And removed the * operator for `counter` from these kind of lines :

```
search((*root)->R, lookingfor, *counter);
```

The fixed code. search.h :

```
struct intnode
{
  void* key;
  struct intnode** R;
  struct intnode** L;
};

void* search(struct intnode** root, int lookingfor, int* counter);
```

search.c :

```
include "search.h"
/* #include "intnode.h" */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Usage:
  search(root, value);
*/

void* search(struct intnode** root, int lookingfor, int* counter) {

  /*COMPARE TO ROOT KEY*/
  /*IF EQUAL*/
  if(int_compare(lookingfor, (*root)->key) == 0) {
    printf("%d exists in tree", lookingfor);
    counter++;
    if ((*root)->R != NULL && (*root)->key == (*root)->R) {
      search((*root)->R, lookingfor, counter);
    }
  }

  /*IF GREATER THAN AND THERE IS A CHILD*/
  else if(int_compare(lookingfor, (*root)->key) == 1 && (*root)->R != NULL) {
    search((*root)->R, lookingfor, counter);
    counter++;
  }

  /*IF LESS THAN AND THERE IS A CHILD*/
  else if(int_compare(lookingfor, (*root)->key) == 2 && (*root)->L != NULL) {
    search((*root)->L, lookingfor, counter);
    counter++;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```